# Geocode of a Intersection of Two Roads

Tags: google-maps, geocoding

Does anyone have a method or an API or a format that I can enter into the google maps API or any other API so I can get a latitude and longitude of an intersection reliably?  For example if I enter "13th and Walnut, Philadelphia, PA" or "13th st and Walnut av, Philadelphia PA" (preferably the first one) the API reliably returns the latitude and longitude.  Google maps API geocoding, when I do a http request, will occasionally get it right, but not often enough and without any pattern.  Sometimes very similar requests will succeed the first time and then fail the second, with the API most often failing to find a location.  I preferably would like an API with a free plan.

Comment: As far as I know Geocoding API can return intersection results only for certain countries. The USA intersections should work with your format.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is: no, there is no reliable API to produce the geocode of a freeform intersection "address". It is too hard to guess the correct location with input that is purposely not a valid address but is being compared to addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is the best option for you. Geocoding is the process of converting addresses (like "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA") into geographic coordinates (like latitude 37.423021 and longitude -122.083739), which you can use to place markers on a map, or position the map.

If you want to access the Google Maps Geocoding API over HTTP, then you can follow the guidelines in the documentation link above.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=13th%20and%20Walnut,%20Philadelphia,%20PA
```

This request will return you a `"lat" : 39.95043578029149` and `"lng" : -75.1607739197085.`

And if you want to know how to code it, then you can check the sample code [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) and this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaroAV/qn8bb8q5/)

**For your question about FREE PLAN**, Geocoding API is free up to 2,500 request per day. And if you reach this limit, it will charge you a $0.50 USD / 1,000 additional requests, up to 100,000 request daily.

For more information about Price details of Google MAPS API, check this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/).

Comment: thank you for your answer. But one more thing, I would like to ask you.. What about its accuracy ?