# Python, Geocoding Intersecting Addresses

Tags: python-3.x, google-geocoding-api

Hello I currently have a great geocoder I built in python using googles geocoder API service. It works great, but the issue that does not work great is that it will not correctly geocode intersecting addresses that are given in the CSV file for example:

```
9th & Upshur St NW
Park Rd & Holmead Pl NW
14th & Girard St NW
10th & K St NW
```

The `&` sign in the addresses are causing an issue when geocoding and resulting in random coordinates.

Is these a work around or way to read these intersecting addresses with `&` sign splitting the 2 addresses?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096991/2573061 -- try 'and' instead of '&'

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 You're awesome, that worked! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should URL encode the query string. After URL encode special symbols will be converted. For example `&` will be converted to `%26`. Resulting request should be something like:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=9th%20%26%20Upshur%20St%20NW&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Have a look at this question to figure out how to URL encode query string in python:

[How to urlencode a querystring in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607551/how-to-urlencode-a-querystring-in-python)

Hope this helps!